# How to store logged in user's info?

Tags: angularjs

I have angular app, user can login using email/password, and server will return token.

Now I have angular service to keep user's data, but if page reload, user logged out.

Should I store that token, in order to make further API calls?

How and where I should store that token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to store the token in local storage, if you are using HTML5. It's as simple as:

```javascript
localStorage['clientToken'] = clientToken;
```

To pass the token back to the server, you can use a HTTP header and a [Angular httpInterceptor](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#description_interceptors):

```javascript
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $log, $location) {
  return {
    'request': function(config) {
      config.headers['clientToken'] = localStorage['clientToken'];
      return config;
    }
  });
```

Some example can be found [here](http://blog.cloudme.org/2013/11/authenticating-single-page-html-applications-with-angular-js-and-flickr/).

Answer (score 0):

For non HTML5 scenarios, you can use simply cookies. Angular provides nice support of it with help of [$cookieStore](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.%24cookieStore).