# Angularjs and security concern

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I have recently implemented and application using Angularjs and spring mvc.
Every thing works fine. In my implementation i have route provider which will redirect the flow to server.

Below is my route provider code

```
angularApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'authenticate.do',
    controller : 'DecideRoamingFlowController'
}).when('/homePage', {
    templateUrl : 'home.do',
    controller : 'HomeController'
}).when('/workPage', {
    templateUrl : 'work.do',
    controller : 'WorkController'
}).when('/auth', {
    templateUrl : 'work.do',
    controller : 'WorkController'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
});
```

My url pattern is something like

```
http://localhost:8080/angularapp/landing.do#/homePage
```

My flow is from home page user enters his credential to be validated, after validation he should be redirected to workPage.

My concern is if i change the value of url from homePage to workPage manually in the address bar i get the work page. Authentication page is by passed, I do not want this behaviour to happen.

How do i go about this?

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS security should be implemented on a different level and might require a little bit of change of mind. Because it is an AJAX based client framework, a user (hacker) can potentially bypass every security measure you implement on the client side. Therefore, security should be implemented on the server side. On the other hand, you always have to check if the user is authenticated / authorized to access the resource on the server and implement appropriate error handling.

That means, on the client side, it might be allowed to see the workPage - but no data should be rendered there, unless the user is logged in.

Your server should respond to all unauthorized AngularJS AJAX requests with status 401 and the client should handle that accordingly.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20678263/1277252) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20261282/1277252), too.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It looks the most logical solution so Will definitely try that out.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using spring mvc it is better to use spring security, which takes care of authentication, redirection on success/failure and also is role based.

Angular Way: you can use event listener

```
      $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState,              fromParams) { // Keep listening for the events and validate .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

Security must be done on the server side:

- Everything that is on the client side isn't secured
- You must secure your REST endpoints with something like Spring Security

This means a hacker could see your "workPage", but as no data can be loaded from the server, he's just seeing a page with empty data.

However, securing an AngularJS application with Spring Security isn't as simple as it may seem, as the framework wasn't meant for that kind of usage in the first place. I spent a lot of time to have a working application, may I suggest you have a look at it:

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app